# How to plot the respective electric field oscillations within an ultrashort pulse envelope if given a spectrum in wavelength?

Tags: plotting

[image]I'm trying to reconstruct the electric field oscillations of an ultrashort pulse from experimental spectrum data readout [600nm to 1100nm]. I have successfully written the codes to convert the temporal profile of ultrashort pulse to spectral domain using FFT. Assume that there is a linear chirp GD spectral phase, I' m wondering how to do the reverse i.e. from spectral to temporal domain (including electric field oscillation, envelope, and temporal phase).

thanks for your help

Regards

Code for temporal to spectral domain:

```
c = 299.792458; (*unit=nm/fs*)
\[Lambda]0 = 800;(*unit=nm*)
f0 = c/\[Lambda]0;(*374.74THz*)(*unit=1/fs*)
\[Omega]0 = 
  2 \[Pi] f0;(*angular freq = 2.35PHz or 2.35*^15*)(*unit=rad/fs*)
\[Epsilon]0 = 
  8.854187817*10^-12*10^-9;(*unit=F/nm*)(*I=1/2\[Epsilon]0 c n (E0)^2 \
*)
n = 1;
E0 = 1 ;
\[Tau]p = 10;(*unit=fs*)
\[CapitalGamma] = 2 Log[2];
\[Tau] = 0.0;(*unit=fs*)

\[Phi]0 = 0 \[Pi];(*absolute carrier envelope offset*)
d\[Phi]1 = 0;(*instantaneous frequency or cause spectral shift*)
d\[Phi]2 = 0.02;(*linear chirp*)(*0.1 max*)
d\[Phi]3 = 
  0.03;(*quadratic chirp cause post- or pre- sub-spectral modulation*)
d\[Phi]4 = 0.005;(*cubic chirp*)
d\[Phi]5 = 0.0000;(*quartic chirp and higher order chirps*)

\[Phi][t_] := \[Phi]0 + d\[Phi]1 (t - \[Tau])^1 + 
   1/2 d\[Phi]2 (t - \[Tau])^2 + 1/6 d\[Phi]3 (t - \[Tau])^3 + 
   1/24 d\[Phi]4 (t - \[Tau])^4 + 
   1/120 d\[Phi]5 (t - \[Tau])^5;(*temporal phase approximate by \
Tylor series*)

pulse[t_] := 
  E0 E^(-\[CapitalGamma] ((t - \[Tau])/\[Tau]p)^2)
    Cos[\[Omega]0 (t - \[Tau])^1 + \[Phi][
      t]](*+E0 \[ExponentialE]^(-\[CapitalGamma]((t-10)/\[Tau]p)^2) \
Cos[\[Omega]0(t-10)^1+\[Phi][t]]*);(*pulse equation*)
tphase = D[\[Phi][t], t];(*instantaneous frequency drift*)
num = 2^15;(*4096,32768*)(*adjust these two value num and tw*)
tw = 5000;(*time window of pulse being observed,larger will cause \
high fft resolution 2ps*)(*unit=fs*)
dt = N[2 tw/num];(*sampling time step*)(*unit=fs*)
df = N[1/(num dt)];(*sampling frequency step*)(*unit=1/fs*)
d\[Lambda] = N[df/c (\[Lambda]0)^2];(*unit=nm*)

Print["Frequency Range = +/- ", N[2 \[Pi] (num/2*df)], "rad/fs"]
Print["Wavelength Range = +/- ", N[(num/2*d\[Lambda])], "nm"]

(*@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
(*@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@         FOR FFT USE        \
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
(*@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)

timevalues = 
  RotateLeft[Table[t, {t, -((num/2 dt) - dt), (num/2 dt), dt}], 
   num/2 - 1];
timelist = pulse /@ timevalues; 
fftshift[flistt_] := 
  RotateRight[flistt, 
   num/2 - 1];(*create a function that ready use for fft*)
fullspectral = Abs@fftshift[Fourier[timelist]];
fullphasee = Arg@fftshift[Fourier[timelist]];
fullphase = 
  ResourceFunction["PhaseUnwrap"][
   fullphasee];(*ResourceFunction["PhaseUnwrap"] need internet to \
unwrap the phase*)

(*@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
(*@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  Frequency domain filter   \
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
(*@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
mm = Ceiling[0/(2 \[Pi] df )];
nn = Ceiling[5/(2 \[Pi] df )];
spectralFreq2 = Take[fullspectral, {num/2 + mm, num/2 + nn}];
(*@@@@@@@@@@@@    Phase    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
phaseFreq2 = Take[fullphase, {num/2 + mm, num/2 + nn}];
(*@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
(*@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  Wavelength domain filter   \
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
(*@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
oo = Ceiling[200/(d\[Lambda] )];
pp = Ceiling[1400/(d\[Lambda] )];
spectralWav2 = Take[fullspectral, {num/2 + oo, num/2 + pp}];
(*@@@@@@@@@@@@    Phase    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
phaseWav2 = Take[fullphase, {num/2 + oo, num/2 + pp}];
(*@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)

Overlay[
 {Show[usp = 
    Plot[pulse[t], {t, -50, +50}, PlotPoints -> 400, 
     PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}, PlotLabel -> "Time domain", 
     ImageSize -> {400, 300}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}, 
     FrameLabel -> {{"Electric Field Amplitude, E(t)", 
        None}, {"Time, t (fs)", None}}, 
     ImagePadding -> {{52, 50}, {47, 20}}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.002], Red}],
   
   (*@@@@@@@@@@@@    USP FWHM    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
   uspdp = Cases[usp, Line[data_] :> data, Infinity][[1]];
   uspdppeaks = Pick[uspdp, PeakDetect[uspdp[[All, 2]]], 1];
   gaussianmodel[
     t_] := (E0 E^(-\[CapitalGamma] ((
        t - \[Tau])/\[CapitalDelta]\[Tau]p)^2) )^1;
   fitt = 
    NonlinearModelFit[uspdppeaks, 
     gaussianmodel[t], {\[CapitalDelta]\[Tau]p}, t];
   fittcomponents = fitt["BestFitParameters"];
   
   Plot[fitt[t], {t, -50, 50}, PlotPoints -> 400,
    PlotLegends -> 
     LineLegend[{Directive[Black, Dashed], 
       Directive[Black, Dashed]}, {Text[
        ToString[fittcomponents[[1]]] <> " fs"], 
       Text["R^2 => " <> ToString[fitt["RSquared"]]]}], 
    PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {400, 300}, Axes -> False, 
    ImagePadding -> {{52, 50}, {47, 20}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.002], Darker[Black, .0]}]],
  (*@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
  
  Plot[tphase, {t, -50, +50}, PlotPoints -> 400, 
   PlotRange -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "", ImageSize -> {400, 300}, 
   Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, All}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{ None, "Temporal Phase, \[Phi](t)"}, {"", None}}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[10, Darker[Green, .5]], Axes -> False, 
   ImagePadding -> {{52, 50}, {47, 20}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.002], Darker[Green, .5]}]}]

Overlay[
 {ListLinePlot[(spectralFreq2)^2, DataRange -> 2 \[Pi] df {mm, nn}, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> "Frequency Domain (Spectral & Phase)", 
   ImageSize -> {400, 300}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"Spectral Intensity, I(\[Omega]), [a.u.]", 
      None}, {"Angular Frequency, \[Omega] (rad/fs)", None}}, 
   ImagePadding -> {{52, 50}, {47, 20}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.002], Red}],
  
  (*@@@@@@@@@@@@    Spectral FWHM    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
  xdatafreq = 
   N[Table[i, {i, (mm*2 \[Pi] df ) , (nn*2 \[Pi] df ) , ((nn*2 \[Pi] \
df ) - (mm*2 \[Pi] df ))/(Length[spectralFreq2] - 1)}]];
  freqdp = Transpose[{xdatafreq, (spectralFreq2)^2}];
  gaussianmodel\[Omega][\[Omega]_, 
    Io\[Omega]_, \[CapitalDelta]\[Omega]_] := 
   Io\[Omega] (E^(-\[CapitalGamma] ((\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)/\
\[CapitalDelta]\[Omega])^2) )^2;
  fit\[Omega] = 
   NonlinearModelFit[freqdp, 
    gaussianmodel\[Omega][\[Omega], 
     Io\[Omega], \[CapitalDelta]\[Omega]], {\[CapitalDelta]\[Omega], 
     Io\[Omega]}, \[Omega]];
  fit\[Omega]components = fit\[Omega]["BestFitParameters"];
  TBP = Abs[\[Tau]p /(2 \[Pi])
      ToExpression[
      StringCases[ToString[fit\[Omega]components[[1]]], 
        NumberString][[1]]]];
  
  Plot[fit\[Omega][\[Omega]], {\[Omega], 0.01, 5.09}, 
   PlotPoints -> 400, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    LineLegend[{Directive[Black, Dashed], Directive[Black, Dashed], 
      Directive[Black, Dashed], 
      Directive[Black, Dashed]}, {Text[
       ToString[fit\[Omega]components[[1]]] <> " rad/fs"], 
      Text[ToString[fit\[Omega]components[[2]]] <> " a.u."], 
      Text["R^2 => " <> ToString[fit\[Omega]["RSquared"]]], 
      Text["TBP" -> Style[ToString[TBP], Bold]]}], PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Thickness[0.002], Darker[Black, .0]}, 
   ImageSize -> {410, 300}, Axes -> False, 
   ImagePadding -> {{50, 52}, {50, 45}}],
  (*@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
  
  ListLinePlot[phaseFreq2, DataRange -> 2 \[Pi] df  {mm, nn}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "", ImageSize -> {400, 300}, 
   Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, All}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{ None, "Spectral Phase, \[Phi](\[Omega])"}, {"", 
      None}}, FrameStyle -> Directive[10, Darker[Green, .5]], 
   ImagePadding -> {{52, 50}, {47, 20}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.002], Darker[Green, .5]}]}]

Overlay[
 {ListLinePlot[(spectralWav2)^2, DataRange -> d\[Lambda] {oo, pp}, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> "Wavelength Domain (Spectral & Phase)", 
   ImageSize -> {400, 300}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"Spectral Intensity, I(\[Lambda]), [a.u.]", 
      None}, {"Wavelength, \[Lambda] (nm)", None}}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[10, Red], 
   ImagePadding -> {{52, 50}, {47, 20}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.002], Red}],
  
  (*@@@@@@@@@@@@    Wavelength FWHM    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
  xdatawav = 
   N[Table[ii, {ii, (oo* d\[Lambda]) , (pp*
        d\[Lambda]) , ((pp*d\[Lambda]) - (oo*d\[Lambda]))/(Length[
          spectralWav2] - 1)}]];
  wavdp = Transpose[{xdatawav, (spectralWav2)^2}];
  gaussianmodel\[Lambda][\[Lambda]_, Io\[Lambda]] := 
   Io\[Lambda] (E^(-\[CapitalGamma] ((\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]0)/\
\[CapitalDelta]\[Lambda])^2) )^2;
  fit\[Lambda] = 
   NonlinearModelFit[wavdp, 
    gaussianmodel\[Lambda][\[Lambda], 
     Io\[Lambda]], {\[CapitalDelta]\[Lambda], Io\[Lambda]}, \[Lambda]];
  fit\[Lambda]components = fit\[Lambda]["BestFitParameters"];
  
  Plot[fit\[Lambda][\[Lambda]], {\[Lambda], 180, 1420}, 
   PlotPoints -> 400, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    LineLegend[{Directive[Black, Dashed], Directive[Black, Dashed], 
      Directive[Black, Dashed]}, {Text[
       ToString[fit\[Lambda]components[[1]]] <> " nm"], 
      Text[ToString[fit\[Lambda]components[[2]]] <> " a.u."], 
      Text["R^2 => " <> ToString[fit\[Lambda]["RSquared"]]]}], 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Thickness[0.002], Darker[Black, .0]}, 
   ImageSize -> {410, 300}, Axes -> False, 
   ImagePadding -> {{50, 52}, {50, 45}}],
  (*@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*)
  
  ListLinePlot[phaseWav2, DataRange -> d\[Lambda] {oo, pp}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "", ImageSize -> {400, 300}, 
   Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, All}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{ None, "Spectral Phase, \[Phi](\[Lambda])"}, {"", 
      None}}, FrameStyle -> Directive[10, Darker[Blue, .0]], 
   ImagePadding -> {{52, 50}, {47, 20}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.002], Darker[Blue, .0]}]}]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please add your data and code.

Comment: added to the question up here. thanks